# Is it possible to change the location of NUnits TestResult.xml

Tags: nunit

When running tests with the NUnit GUI application, is it possible to change the location of where NUnit creates the TestResult.xml file after the test has completed? It is usually created in the same folder as the solution or dll file.

I know it can be changed when using the command line nunit-console.exe but I haven't been able to find an option to change it on the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running my tests in NUnit GUI I can manually go into (Tools->Save Result as XML) then a file explorer is popped allowing me to select where the XML file is saved.

Comment: That option is disabled for me, is it only enabled after a test is run?

Comment: Update: Yes it is available after a test is run!

Comment: Yes sir, as soon as your suite or individual test is run; you should be able to follow the commands above!

Comment: I've edited this answer to indicate that the option is available AFTER a test run.